# Comparing two object lists using one of the object atributes

Tags: java

I have two object lists that needs to be compared. The objects have the name atribute and i'd like to check if one object with that name, is present in the other list.

I've came across the ListUtils.subtract method, but i've only seen people using it with types like Int or String...

Can it be used with custom object types?

EDIT:

```
Myclass{
    private String name;
    public getName(){
        return this.name;
    }

}
```

I have two lists of this object type:

```
List<MyClass> list1;
List<MyClass> list2;
```

One of these lists is created with some sql queries. The other one is created checking some files in a server. The number of objects in these lists could be the same, or one or the other could have more objects.

Is there a way to get the objects that are in one list, but not in the other list?

Something like this:

```
List result = ListUtils.subract (list1,list2);
```

But using the name atribute.

Comment: Code would be nice. Also clarify the question. What EXACTLY do you want to happen when two objects have the same name in different lists?

Comment: overriding the `equals` method? Tried this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use ListUtils.subtract with your two lists. For it to work, you have to define the `equals` method of your custom class to return true if and only if the name attribute is the same for both objects.

<s>That said, `ListUtils.substract` don't give you the intersection between the two lists. For that you would use `ListUtils.retainAll`. You can also simply use `List.retainAll` but it would modify one of your list instead of creating a copy, so you should create such a copy yourself.</s>

Edit: So you don't want intersection, you really want a subtraction. It is fine this way, just write the equals of your object like this:

```
bool equals(Object other) {
    if (other==null || !other instanceof MyClass) {
        return false;
    }
    return name.equals(other.name); // assume name is never null. You can check for that
}
```

You can also use `Collection.removeAll` on your list.

It is not always practical to override `equals`, for example if you have different scenarios where you want to compare according to other attributes. In that case, you can use a `Comparator` and `Collections2.filter` from [Guava library](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Collections2.html).

Answer (score 0):

Make the objects implement [`Comparable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html). In `compareTo()` method, compare according to name attribute.

Answer (score 0):

you can also use comparator and comparable. Here is an example http://www.digizol.com/2008/07/java-sorting-comparator-vs-comparable.html

Answer (score -3):

The answer is no rtf
Why you don't use Google to find it yourself
Why you don't use the ide to show you the documentation

i thinlk override equals solve the problem but is a hack

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String arg[]) {
        ArrayList<Dog> firstGroup = new ArrayList<Dog>();

        firstGroup.add(new Dog("Rintintin"));
        firstGroup.add(new Dog("Courage"));
        firstGroup.add(new Dog("Scooby-Dooby-Do"));

        ArrayList<Dog> secondGroup = new ArrayList<Dog>();

        secondGroup.add(new Dog("fido"));
        secondGroup.add(new Dog("Courage"));
        secondGroup.add(new Dog("Rintintin"));

        List<Dog> filterByName = filterByName(firstGroup,secondGroup);

        System.out.print(Arrays.toString(filterByName.toArray()));
    }

    private static List<Dog> filterByName(ArrayList<Dog> firstGroup, ArrayList<Dog> secondGroup) {
        List<Dog> result=new ArrayList<>();
        for (Dog orginal : firstGroup) 
            for (Dog finDog : secondGroup) 
                if(orginal.getName().equals(finDog.getName()))
                    result.add(new Dog(orginal.getName()));
        return result;
    }


}
```